# Computing only necessary rows of a matrix product

Tags: matlab, sparse-matrix, matrix-multiplication

Suppose I have a large (but possibly sparse) matrix `A`, which is *K-by-K* in dimension. I have another *K-by-1* vector, `b`.

Let `Ax=b`. If I am only interested in the first `n` rows, where `n < K`, of `x`, then one way of dealing with this in MATLAB is to calculate `x=A\b` and take the first `n` elements.

If the dimension `K` is so large that the entire computation infeasible, is there any other way to get these elements?

Comment: This is an interesting question, however, I suspect it's more of a mathematical question than a programming question. On first glance, I found [two](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0898122188901721) [papers](https://www.degruyter.com/view/j/rnam.1989.4.issue-6/rnam.1989.4.6.453/rnam.1989.4.6.453.xml) which might possibly be related... Ask on Mathematics.SE, maybe?

Comment: Thanks! Will take a look!

Answer (score 1):

I guess one way would be to rearrange the columns of A and rows of x so that the elements you are interested in occur at the end of x. Then you would reduce [A,b] to row echelon form. Finally, to get the components you are after, you take the lower right hand nxn submatrix of the modified A (let's call it An) and you solve the reduced system An * xn = bn, where xn denotes the submarine of x that you are interested in, and bn  denotes the last n rows of b after the row echelon reduction.

I mean, the conversion here to echelon form is still expensive, but you don't need to solve for the rest of the components in x, which can save you time.

Answer (score 1):

Just an idea: You could try to use Block Matrix inversion: if you block your matrix into `A = [A11, A12;A21, A22]`, where `A11` is `n x n`, you can compute the blocks of its inverse `B = inv(A) = [B11, B12;B21, B22]` via [Block Matrix Inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix#Block_matrix_inversion). There are different versions of it, you could use the one where the Schur complement you use is only of size `n x n`. I'm not quite sure whether it is possible to avoid any inversion that scales with `K`, but you could look into it.

Your solution is then `x(1:n) = [B11, B12]*b`. It saves you from ever computing B21, B22. Still, I'm not sure if it is worth it. Depends on the dimensions I guess.

Here is one version, though this still needs the inverse of A22 which is `(K-n)x(K-n)`:

```
K = 100;
n = 10;
A = randn(K,K);
b = randn(K,1);
% reference version: full inverse
xfull = inv(A)*b;

% blocks of A
A11 = A(1:n,1:n);A12 = A(1:n,n+1:K);A21 = A(n+1:K,1:n);A22 = A(n+1:K,n+1:K);
% blocks of inverse
A22i = inv(A22);                % not sure if this can be avoided
B11 =  inv(A11 - A12*A22i*A21);
B12 = -B11*A12*A22i;

% solution
x_n = [B11,B12]*b;

disp(x_n - xfull(1:n))
```

**edit**: Of course, this computes the inverse "explicitly" and as such is probably much slower than just solving the LSE. It could be worth it, if you had several vectors b you want to fit for a fixed A.

Comment: The mathematically correct name for this algorithm is the [Schur complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement). Also, you should substitute `inv(A22)` with `A22\eye(m)` with `m = k-n`.

Comment: You'll notice that I did already mention "Schur complement" in my reply. ;-) Out of curiosity: Do you think that `A22\eye(K-n)` is faster than `inv(A22)`? I don't know, but I'd be a bit surprised to be honest.